# Can't use Gurobi on Linux because: <installdir>/gurobi811/linux64/bin/python2.7: not found

Tags: python, gurobi

I am currently trying to install Gurobi on Linux (Linux Mint Cinnamon) following [this instruction](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/quickstart_linux/software_installation_guid.html). The installation does not result in any issue, but as soon as I am trying "gurobi.sh" in the bash terminal, I get following issue:

```
(base) rr12@rr12-VirtualBox:~$ gurobi.sh
/home/rr12/anaconda3/bin/gurobi.sh: 18: /home/rr12/anaconda3/bin/gurobi.sh: ~/gurobi811/linux64/bin/python2.7: not found
```

I have tried to google the issue but the two results are not very helpful. I am new to Linux so maybe it is a simple thing to change but I really don't have a clue where to start.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you install Gurobi via Anaconda before? `gurobi.sh` should be started from the Gurobi installation directory and not from within Anaconda. What seems strange is that the error message is pointing to `~/gurobi811/linux` and not to `~/gurobi811/linux64`. Can you check, which of those paths exists?

Comment: I have tried both ways to install Gurobi. First just the normal installation without Anaconda and, after that one didn't worked out, I installed it also with anaconda, following this instruction:

https://www.gurobi.com/de/gurobi-and-anaconda-for-windows/

The missing "64" from the Path is my mistake as I couldn't copy the error (because of the virtual machine). So I just missed it (and changed it now in my previous post).

I have solved the issue now. Instead of setting the bashrc file to ~/gurobi811/linux64/bin I set it to /home/usr/gurobi811/linux64/bin.